# Tracking emails clicks that is not spam

Tags: php, email, tracking, redirect, email-spam

I'm placing various advertising within emails the site I'm working on sends out. I want to track these but not risk the emails being caught as spam.

From my research it seems the going way to track clicks on links in emails is to use redirection. However I want to know the affect this has on spam flagging for the emails.

I have spent much time making the emails as spam free as possible. I understand that some spam detection till run the links within the email and if a redirect is detected it is much more likely to treat the email as spam. Even more so if the redirect is to another domain.

Is this correct? Having redirected URLs in an email will increase its spam score?
And then what is the best way to track clicks on links in emails?
Or it is just not reliably possible?
Does it matter on the type of redirection? IE Java Script or PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use links generated by `Google Analytics URL Builder` 
It won't make your e-mails spam and also helps you to track the clicks on the links and generate analytics for you.

Following is the link -
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Redirected links are the industry standard way of tracking clicks. All Email Service Providers do it.

A really quick way for you to implement this without using an ESP like Mailchimp, Campaign Monitor etc, is to use Bitly, or any other link shortening service.